# What markup language is <sup>?

Tags: support, editor, markdown-rendering

I just found the usage of `<sup>` in a SO question to give superscripts as follows:

y = x<sup>2</sup> + 4*x - 5

This seems to be useful. I was wondering in general what markup language this is?

Also if I make it code, the `<sup>` won't work:

```
y = x<sup>2</sup> + 4*x - 5
```

Any way to make the markup and code sample work together?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stack Overflow uses Markdown, with support for [a limited selection of HTML](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites).

You can find additional information on formatting your posts in these links:

- [Editing Help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)
- [Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

You can make html work in a code block by using `<pre>` (or `<code>` for an inline code block) tags instead of indentation or backticks to mark it.

So this:

```
<pre>y = x<sup>2</sup> + 4*x - 5</pre>
```

Will render like you want:

```
y = x2 + 4*x - 5
```

Comment: Did you insert the last `<code></code>` on purpose?

Comment: @MarounMaroun Whoops. No I did not. Fixed now.

Comment: Cool. Now I can die in peace ;)

Answer (score 6):

It's not markdown as used in the Stack Exchange editor, but a plain HTML tag.

The Stack Overflow markdown allows to incorporate certain HTML tags.

> Any way to make the markup and code sample work together?

No, not unless you make the code section using HTML as well:

```
<pre>y = x<sup>2</sup> + 4*x - 5</pre>
```

```
y = x2 + 4*x - 5
```

Comment: ht**ML** is by definition a **M**arkup **L**anguage. So it is markup.

Comment: @Liam Valid nitpick.

Comment: Ha ha, sorry.. :)